# re-adding www folder to xcode phonegap project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova

I had accidently removed the www folder from my phonegap project in xcode. I have relocated it and moved it back into the xcode project folder in finder. But, its not showing up in the project in xcode. it used to come up as a blue folder on the left side. How do I get the xcode project to recongnise its there again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in project tree -> add files to "YourProjectName" -> select your www folder, make sure that "create folder references for any added folders" is checked, click "add".